# Mongoose population is not working. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In this model, I am connecting a person to father. I want to make a person to father relationship. As you can see in the schema I used ref and type is ObjectId. But I am not getting any kind of fields from father collection How can I retrieve fields? Is it possible that it not working because the strict mode is disabled?

```js
const Person_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "Full_name": {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    "Father_name": {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Father",
        required: true
    }
}, {strict: false})

const Father_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "Full_name": {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, {strict: false})

const Person = mongoose.model('Person', Person_schema, 'Person');

const Father = mongoose.model('Father', Father_schema, 'Father');

async function Save_person(){
    const Person_data = [new Person({
        "Full_name": "Bhavin Shah",
        "Father_name": "5c8892fb5049fb176c548cc1"
    }), new Person({
        "Full_name": "Urvil Shah",
        "Father_name": "5c8892fb5049fb176c548cc1"
    })];
    
    const saved_person = await Person.insertMany(Person_data);

    console.log(saved_person);
}

async function Save_father(){
    const Father_data = new Father({
        "Full_name": "Ashok Kumar"
    });

    const saved_father = await Father_data.save();

    console.log(saved_father);
}

async function Get_person(){
    const person_data = await Person.find().populate('Father', {'Full_name': 1});

    console.log(person_data);
}
```

Comment: Is this value (5c8892fb5049fb176c548cc1) exists as `_id` in father collection?

Comment: I am not sure but I think you need to use objectId when inserting in function not string when defined as an mongoId type in schema
mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5c8892fb5049fb176c548cc1');

Answer (score 0):

```
async function Get_person(){
    //const person_data = await Person.find().populate('Father', {'Full_name': 1}); // This is wrong.

    const person_data = await Person.find().populate('Father_name', {'Full_name': 1}); // You have to put the field that you want to populate
    console.log(person_data);
}
```